# Retrieve all sites and all subsites from the SharePoint REST API

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

Using the SharePoint Online REST API, I'm trying to retrieve a list of all sites *and* subsites.

This API gives me all top level sites, but no subsites:

```
https://{mycompany}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query
   ?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site'
```

Either of these APIs gives me all sub-sites of the root top level site:

```
https://{mycompany}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query
   ?querytext='contentclass:STS_Web'

https://{mycompany}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?
   querytext='*'
   &refinementfilters='contentclass:equals("STS_Web")'
```

I'd like a **single query** which retrieves all sites *and* all of their subsites --
not just subsites of the root site.

**Edit:**

Now I've had time to come back to this, as suggested by @Gautam Sheth I've tried this:

```
https://{mycompany}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query
   ?querytext='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web'
   &selectproperties='Title,Path'&rowlimit=500
```

It's not quite working though. In a site structured like so, only the checked (✅) sites and subsites are being returned in the response:

- ✅ Example Inc - Team Site *(the default root site)*

  - ✅ Subsite of Example Inc - Team Site

    - Nested subsite of Subsite of Example Inc - Team Site
    - Nested subsite #2 of Subsite of Example Inc - Team Site
  - Subsite #2 of Example Inc - Team Site
  - Subsite #3 of Example Inc - Team Site
- ✅ David's Test Site *(another top level site)*

  - Subsite of David's Test Site

Comment: To be clear, this will not retrieve all sites, only the ones the current user has access to see. Event tenant admins will not have access to all sites by default, unless you put them there.

Comment: Agreed. Also, I only want the sites that the current user has access to. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

✅ If you *just* want to get a list of site & subsite **URLs**, you can cheat slightly.

Instead of looking for the sites or subsites, look for a `/path/to/newsfeed.aspx` entry instead. This appears to be present for all sites and subsites.

Here's the URL:

```
https://{mycompany}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query
   ?querytext='*/newsfeed.aspx'&trim&selectproperties='ParentLink'
```

The `ParentLink` property contains the base URL for the site/sub-site.

While this is correct, it just feels like the wrong way of doing things.

This method also **does not return the actual name of the site/sub-site**, so is only a partial answer, but the best I can find right now.

---

If you can use the Microsoft Graph, it's much easier...

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites?search=*
```

...will give all sites and subsites with their names

Comment: Hey this sort of answers my question over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58029947/how-to-lookup-all-sites-with-the-microsoft-graph-api
Thanks!

Comment: How would you write the Microsoft Graph line above using msGraphClientFactory?
At the moment I'm using .api("sites") but that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `STS_Site` and `STS_Web` both in your queryText.

Your REST API endpoint should be as below:

```
https://{mycompany}.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?
querytext='contentclass:STS_Site contentclass:STS_Web'
&selectproperties='Title,Path'&rowlimit=500
```

Am able to get deep subsites as well using the above endpoint . Check the below screenshot which shows the deep subsite.

[image]

Comment: hey @dvdsmpsn, did you try this REST api endpoint ? if it worked for you, could you please mark it as answer ?

Comment: Unfortunately, this still didn't give me a list of all sites & subsites  - I've updated the question with my new findings though

Comment: Run this code with Site Collection admin rights and then run it with normal user rights. It could be that the user doesnt have the rights on the deeper subsite because permissions or inheritance were broken. Are you able to view these sites via UI using that user ?

Comment: Besides that ensure that the site is indeed allowed to indexed. Go to Site Settings > Search and offline availability and ensure that `Allow this site to appear in search results` value is set to Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the updates. I am actually running these searches as the site admin, right now. All the sites and subsites have been created by this user, and have "Allow this site to appear in search results?" set to *Yes*

Answer (score 2):

You can use below code to achieve above functionality : 
Below code fetches Subsites of root site and their subsite mentioning their parents as well. Hope this solves your issue

```
//common Ajax call function which sends back the response call
function GETMethodAjaxCall(url, success) {
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: url,
    headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
        success(response);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert("error")
    }
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {

var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/webs";

GETMethodAjaxCall(url, function(data) {
    $.each(data.d.results, function(index, value) {
        console.log("Site: " + value.Title + " " + "is Parent Site");

        GETMethodAjaxCall(value.Url + "/_api/Web/webs", function(data) {
            $.each(data.d.results, function(ind, val) {
                console.log("SubSite: " + val.Title + " " + "is child of " + value.Title);
            });
        });

    });    
});
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately, I need a single API call to get these.

Comment: your inner call shows only the last subsite. It does not show the rest? How can I show them in a master, child fashion?