# Get every sites in a tenant using SharePoint API

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am developing a SharePoint solution using Django.

How can I make the user login in my app using SharePoint login and list out all the available sites inside that particular tenant?
I have seen SharePoint API to get files and lists, of that I am afraid I have to provide site URL explicitly!!!

Is there any way I can make use of SharePoint login and access all the sites and contents?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You could use search api:

```
/_api/search/query?querytext='contentclass:sts_site'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the rest api, you can refer to this similar question for solutions: [Retrieve all sites and all subsites from the SharePoint REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/230187/retrieve-all-sites-and-all-subsites-from-the-sharepoint-rest-api)

You could also use the Graph API, the documentation should point you in the right direction: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/sharepoint?view=graph-rest-1.0